# How can i align these div containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to align 4 divs currently next to each other with a 20px margin "top,bottom,left,right"

I have tried to add display:inline; to the container to display them all inline but that didn't work, I have also tried to float them left , still not workin.

Could someone explain to me how to get 4 divs to display next to each other without adding a different position to them all?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42Rw7/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="img"><center><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1eIdJ43s3yE/Sw1h8khv0FI/AAAAAAAAEic/L0FzKdsbxkU/s1600/usa-flag.jpg" alt="" width="194" height="194"/></center>    </div>
<div class="title" id="title"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></div>
<div class="text"><i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</i></div>
<div class="button"><a href="#">text link</a><div/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #BDC3C7;
}
.container{
position:absolute;
background-color:#ECF0F1;
width:300px;
height:550px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.title{
height:35px;
}
#title{ color:white;
font-size:28px;
text-align:center;
background-color:navy; 
background-image:url(img/strip.jpg);}

.img{ background-color:#2C3E50; 
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.text{
font-size:18px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:25px;
margin-right:25px;
}
.button{
width:100%;
height:33px;
background-color:#2C3E50; 
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
font-size:25px; text-align:center;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
a { text-decoration:none }
a:link {color:#2ecc71;}
a:hover {color:#3498db;}
```

Comment: Your html is wrong. Each container is in another container class, you should fix the html before you try to position them.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but even if it was i still cant align them

Comment: Small fixes your html and css --> http://jsfiddle.net/Nept/42Rw7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your html that are probably the source of your frustration.

The main issue with the html was that you weren't closing your .button div correctly. Another issue was that you were using the same id multiple times.  That's just not valid.

Also, I removed the deprecated and otherwise unneeded code and css.  Please **never** use `<center>` again, okay? Promise me.  There's no place for a center tag in 2014. ;-)  I replaced it with `margin: 0 auto;`.  If you don't understand what that does you can look up how to center things in css.

I've cleaned up your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/b73Z9/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1eIdJ43s3yE/Sw1h8khv0FI/AAAAAAAAEic/L0FzKdsbxkU/s1600/usa-flag.jpg" alt="" width="194" height="104"/></div>
    <div class="title"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></div>
    <div class="text"><i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</i></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">text link</a></div>
</div>
<!-- 2 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1eIdJ43s3yE/Sw1h8khv0FI/AAAAAAAAEic/L0FzKdsbxkU/s1600/usa-flag.jpg" alt="" width="194" height="104"/></div>
    <div class="title"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></div>
    <div class="text"><i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</i></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">text link</a></div>
</div>
    <!-- 3 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1eIdJ43s3yE/Sw1h8khv0FI/AAAAAAAAEic/L0FzKdsbxkU/s1600/usa-flag.jpg" alt="" width="194" height="104"/></div>
    <div class="title"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></div>
    <div class="text"><i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</i></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">text link</a></div>
</div>
    <!-- 4 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1eIdJ43s3yE/Sw1h8khv0FI/AAAAAAAAEic/L0FzKdsbxkU/s1600/usa-flag.jpg" alt="" width="194" height="104"/></div>
    <div class="title"><i>Lorem Ipsum</i></div>
    <div class="text"><i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</i></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">text link</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #BDC3C7;
}
.container{
    background-color:#ECF0F1;
    width:300px;
    height:450px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}   
.title {
    height:35px;
    color:white;
    font-size:28px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:navy;
    background-image:url(img/strip.jpg);
}
.img{ 
    background-color:#2C3E50; 
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.text{
  font-size:18px;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-right:25px;
}
.button{
    width:100%;
    height:33px;
    background-color:#2C3E50; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size:25px; text-align:center;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
a { 
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link {
    color:#2ecc71;
}
a:hover {
    color:#3498db;
}
```

Comment: guess i cant rush a website, add me on skype AfterlifeGamingHD and thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I saw was that the closing `div` tags for `.button` were `<div/>` instead of `</div>`. With those fixed, I was able to align them all up using `float: left`

I also noticed that you want your `.button` to be at the very bottom of the container. Since you're using `position: absolute` to make that happen, the `.button` are staying on top of each other at `bottom: 0` To fix that problem I made each container to be `relative`.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;

  /* Other rules */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TNP8u/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10pc;
  width: 30pc;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 10pc;
  width: 7pc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that this doesn't answer your question with your codes but it's something similar to what you're looking for.